# Ask the user to choose the directory location and then count the number of csv files generated in that specific location in the last 15 minutes

Tags: powershell

Here is my problem.  I want the user to choose any location. Here is my script to choose a specific location.

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory="")

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}


$a = Get-Folder
```

Now with in the selected folder, I wanted to count only the number of csv files arrived in last 15 minutes and then output the count of files.

This is what i have so far.

```
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}


$a = Get-Folder
```

This is what I expect.

```
Number of csv files in last 15 minutes = xxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, updating your function as follow should work for your need:

```
Function Get-FileCount {
    param(
        [string] $InitialDirectory = $PWD.Path,
        [datetime] $TimeLimit = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-15)
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.windows.forms

    $browser = [System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog]@{
        Description  = "Select a folder"
        RootFolder   = "MyComputer"
        SelectedPath = $InitialDirectory
    }

    if($browser.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        Get-ChildItem $browser.SelectedPath -Filter *.csv -File -Force |
            Where-Object LastWriteTime -GE $TimeLimit |
            Measure-Object |
            ForEach-Object { 'Number of csv files in last 15 minutes = {0}' -f $_.Count }
    }
}

Get-FileCount
```

Instead of returning `$foldername.SelectedPath` from it, you can use the path to then get the `.Csv` files in it with `Get-ChildItem` and then count them and output the total count.